# How do I use labels in LLDB memory reads?

Tags: memory, nasm, lldb

I'm just getting started with LLDB after decades of using GDB. I've run into what seems like an absurdly simple request: show me the contents of memory at a specific label.  The context: a trivial Hello World program written in NASM, which actually works when I run it from the command line, and when I run it from inside LLDB.  But my problem is reading memory in that program.  When it hits the breakpoint at 'main':

```
Process 16808 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x0000000100003f99 lldb_prob`main at lldb_prob.asm:10
   7    _main:
   8        ; Print greeting
   9        mov     eax, 0x2000004
-> 10       mov     edi, 1
   11       lea     rsi, [msg]
   12       mov     edx, msg.len
   13       syscall
Target 0: (lldb_prob) stopped.
(lldb) x -s1 -fx -c32 main
error: invalid start address expression.
error: address expression "main" evaluation failed
(lldb) x -s1 -fx -c32 _main
error: invalid start address expression.
error: address expression "_main" evaluation failed
(lldb) x -s1 -fx -c32 0x100003f99
0x100003f99: 0xbf 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x48 0x8d 0x35
0x100003fa1: 0x5b 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xba 0x0e 0x00 0x00
0x100003fa9: 0x00 0x0f 0x05 0xb8 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x02
0x100003fb1: 0xbf 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x0f 0x05 0x01
```

So I can read the memory, but I can't use the label in a memory read as I can in setting a breakpoint.  Or, to be more precise, I haven't figured out how to use labels to read memory.  Any help would be appreciated.